# Getting TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'selectedBookList'

Tags: vuejs3, pinia

Store

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useBookStore = defineStore({
  id: "book",
  state: () => ({
    selectedBookList: {},
    selectedPrayerList: [],
    tableOfPrayerList: [],
  }),
  
});
```

Usage:

```
<script setup>
import { useBookStore } from "../store/bookStore";
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
...

// Pinia - BookStore
const bookStore = useBookStore();

...

function getToP() {
    ...
    return prayerTitleDisplays;
}

bookStore.selectedBookList = [];       <= error thrown here
bookStore.selectedPrayerList = getNewFilteredPrayers();
bookStore.tableOfPrayerList = getToP();
</script>

<template>
  ...
</template>
```

I have checked the following questions, but there solution doesn't seem to apply to my case:

- [Vuejs3 pinia error: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76200680/vuejs3-pinia-error-set-on-proxy-trap-returned-falsish-for-property)
- [Vue3: Uncaught TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'NewTodo'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648897/vue3-uncaught-typeerror-set-on-proxy-trap-returned-falsish-for-property-ne)

Comment: works find in vue sfc playground, please make a reproducible example